# Improving performance of a GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(...) > 1 in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I'm trying to select the orders that are part of a trip with multiple orders.

I tried many approaches but can't find how to have a performant query.

To reproduce the problem here is the setup (here it's 100 000 rows, but really it's more 1 000 000 rows to see the timeout on db-fiddle).

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```sql
create table trips (id bigint primary key);
create table orders (id bigint primary key, trip_id bigint);
create index trips_idx on trips (id);
create index orders_idx on orders (id);
create index orders_trip_idx on orders (trip_id);

insert into trips (id) select seq from generate_series(1,100000) seq;
insert into orders (id, trip_id) select seq, floor(random() * 100000 + 1) from generate_series(1,100000) seq;
```

---

**Query #1**

```sql
explain analyze select orders.id
from orders
inner join trips on trips.id = orders.trip_id
inner join orders trips_orders on trips_orders.trip_id = trips.id
group by orders.id, trips.id
having count(trips_orders) > 1
limit 50
;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/5851)

Here is what pgmustard gives me on the real query:

[image: pgmustard]

Comment: oops forgot to create the indexes in DB Fiddle

Comment: That query can never be fast. Give it enough `work_mem` to boost it somewhat.

Comment: Simply changing the fiddle PostgreSQL version to match the version you say you are using improves things by 100 fold.

Comment: > postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.5 (Homebrew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need the join on trips? You could try

```sql
SELECT shared.id
FROM orders shared
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders other 
              WHERE other.trip_id = shared.trip_id
              AND other.id != shared.id
              )
;
```

to replace the group by with a hash join, or

```sql
SELECT unnest(array_agg(orders.id))
FROM orders
GROUP BY trip_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
;
```

to hopefully get Postgres to just use the trip_id index.

Comment: thanks, I tested the query https://gist.github.com/dorianmariefr/8b288f9bb1ffc5f60f60694b3dbc9ba2 and I'm getting 191ms instead of 6s

Comment: @hisocrat.. can you please explain how count(*) is working here. does mean count(array_agg(orders.id)) and then unnest...BTW.. interesting approach.. appreciate it